# Failed to get data from MS Access

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a PC with Windows 10 64bit as OS, Visual Studio 2012, SQL Server 2012 64bit, Microsoft Office 2016. I'm running this script to get data from MS Access file

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserId,CheckTime
FROM            OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','D:\att2000.mdb';'admin';'',CheckInOut)
```

Before I run that script, I've installed Microsoft Database Engine 2016 then run a few scripts

```
   EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
   EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
   RECONFIGURE
   GO
```

and this

```
   USE [master]
   GO

   EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
   GO

   EXEC master . dbo. sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
   GO
```

Then I set the `msqlserver` service account to local account, after that I can get data from MS Access. But sometimes I get this error

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)

I cannot connect to database engine and have to restart SQL Server, I can run query to other tables in SQL Server as usual but for that particular
script to get data from MS Access, it fails and I got that error. Then I noticed that 'SQL Server Configuration Manager' disappeared from program list.
I tried to search but can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Add SQL Server Configuration Server as below:

1 - Start —> Run —> mmc.exe
2 - In Menu Bar —> File —> Add/Remove Snap-in (or CTRL + M)
3 - Add SQL Server Configuration Manager and click OK

Try to restart the services and let me know if the problem persist.

Comment: i've done what you told but the error still occurs and the services stopped again

Comment: Ok, check SQL Server’s Error Logs and Log Application from Event Viewer and share with us the errors

Comment: Any news about it?